# How do I mock a mocks fields in Grails 2.3.9?

Tags: grails

I'm a Grails/Groovy newb. I've written a script or two in Groovy but never tests. My background is Java.

Project is an ancient part of a test harness that they want updated for Java 8 and our latest jars.

I've been reading this:
http://docs.grails.org/2.3.9/guide/testing.html
... but there's much I don't understand. The test I'm trying to correct is responding with errors that pertain to null-ability.

Test looks like this:

```
@TestFor(SomethingController)
@Mock(Something)
class SomethingControllerTests {
...
    void testDelete() {
        controller.delete()
        assert flash.message != null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/somethingPills/list'

        response.reset()

        populateValidParams(params)

        def SomethingPills = new SomethingPills(params)

        def saveValueReturned = SomethingPills.save()

        assert saveValueReturned != null
        assert SomethingPills.count() == 1

        params.id = SomethingPills.id

        controller.delete()

        assert SomethingPills.count() == 0
        assert SomethingPills.get(somethingPills.id) == null
        assert response.redirectedUrl == '/somethingPills/list'
    }

}
```

The result is that an Exception is chucked out at the `assert saveValueReturned != null` line indicating that the save was unsuccessful. If I dig into the `Something` mock during a debug run, I see that all the fields are null except for an errors field. The errors field lists not-nullablle errors pertaining to several fields. Clearly what I have to do is set these within the mock. What I need are clues on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code, it looks SomethingPills is a Grails domain class. Since you are passing params and trying to save, you need to populate the params with values needed for SomethingPills to save, otherwise SomethingPills will throw ValidationException error.

The populateValidParams(params) may not be populating params with all the properties that are needed for SomethingPills to save.

Comment: Yes. In fact the populateValidParams method is empty. If I'm understanding correctly, all I have to do is populate it with appropriate values?

Comment: OK, I had tried to do this before and it didn't work. Now I realize why. There are constraints to be met.  Just learned about em.